# How Can I Update a String's Value without Changing Its Position with a Thread Job? [Python]

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, ncurses

I will have two jobs in my script. Once a job started other will run async. I used Thread for this. And this thread will return some info while other count that info.

What I want to do is while counter's value is changing, thread also be continue to run.

Display that I want:

```
-----------------------------------------
Count: 5
-----------------------------------------
thread keeps running...
thread keeps running...
thread keeps running...
```

Actually I achive this goal using `curses` module, but this is not exactly what I wanted. Because when I press `^C` terminal contents is gone. I want them to freeze in the screen.

Code with curses:

```py
import sys
import time
import queue
import signal
import curses
import threading


def ctrl_c_handler(*args):
    sys.exit(0)


signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, ctrl_c_handler)

MESSAGE = "thread keeps running..."


def print_func(message):
    return message


def new_window(stdscr):
    que = queue.Queue()

    curses.curs_set(False)

    y, x = stdscr.getmaxyx()

    draw = x * "-"

    i = 3
    count = 1
    while True:
        thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda q, arg1: q.put(print_func(arg1)), args=(que, MESSAGE,), daemon=True)
        thread.start()
        result = que.get()

        try:
            stdscr.addstr(0, 0, draw)
            stdscr.addstr(1, 0, f"Count: {str(count)}")
            stdscr.addstr(2, 0, draw)
            stdscr.addstr(i, 0, result)

        except curses.error:
            pass

        stdscr.refresh()
        time.sleep(0.1)

        i += 1
        count += 1

        if i == y:
            stdscr.clear()
            i = 3


curses.wrapper(new_window)
```

Is there a way to achive the same goal without using curses, or curses with no loss of contents?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```py
import sys
import time
import queue
import signal
import curses
import threading


ctrl_c_pressed_event = threading.Event()

def ctrl_c_handler(*args):
    ctrl_c_pressed_event.set()


signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, ctrl_c_handler)

MESSAGE = "thread keeps running..."


def print_func(message):
    return message


def new_window(stdscr):
    que = queue.Queue()

    curses.curs_set(False)

    y, x = stdscr.getmaxyx()

    draw = x * "-"

    i = 3
    count = 1
    while True:
        if ctrl_c_pressed_event.isSet():
            stdscr.getkey()
            break
        thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda q, arg1: q.put(print_func(arg1)), args=(que, MESSAGE,), daemon=True)
        thread.start()
        result = que.get()
        try:
            stdscr.addstr(0, 0, draw)
            stdscr.addstr(1, 0, f"Count: {str(count)}")
            stdscr.addstr(2, 0, draw)
            stdscr.addstr(i, 0, result)
        except curses.error:
            pass
        stdscr.refresh()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        i += 1
        count += 1
        if i == y:
            stdscr.clear()
            i = 3


curses.wrapper(new_window)
print('Program ended')
```

Comment: I think this method the finest I can get. Without pressing an extra key I mean. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: Yes, but if I resize the terminal this answer not works :( I got this error `Program endedart()`

Answer (score 2):

The `curses.wrapper` does this. change your `ctrl_c_handler` function as follow:

```
def ctrl_c_handler(*args):
    curses.nocbreak()
    scr.keypad(False)
    curses.echo()
    sys.exit(0)
```

and instead of using the `wrapper` function start the `new_window` like this:

```
scr = curses.initscr()
new_window(scr)
```

Comment: This answer does the trick, almost. Without using `curses.endwin()` terminal is gone mad.